# unable to find the reference to the content property in a stylesheet

Tags: css, css-content

Firstly let me admit that I am a beginner in CSS. I recently came across a nice website: http://www.sitepoint.com/better-solution-managing-z-index-sass/ and was curious to know how the "3" is displayed alongside "CSS". When I tried to check through the firebug, I saw a class name ".category-css .icon-category:before" which contains `content` property which has some strange content. 
Could you please let me know where is `content` property pointing to. I know this might be the silliest question, but I am clueless.

Comment: better post a DEMO with relevant HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `<i class="icon-category>` they are setting a `font-family: 'sitepoint', Sans-Serif;`, on the `:before` element the `content` element is using a [Unicode](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20a%20unicode), which will relate to a character from their custom font 'sitepoint'.

For example, [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) uses unicodes for it's characters, as you can see each character has a unique code next to it.